# Not able to retrieve source from org using vs code

Tags: metadata, vs-code, retrieve

I am trying to retrieve all the metadata from my developer org through vs code but I am facing this issue :

sfdx-project.json file. Add this location to your "packageDirectories" value, or deploy or retrieve a different file or directory. For details about sfdx-project.json, see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm

sfdx-project.json:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "name": "SFDCFinal",
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "54.0"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read the cited documentation? Have you set up source tracking on your dev org? Did you authenticate and authorize your dev org to allow sfdx CLI access?

Comment: I recommend you [edit] your question to add detail of your `sfdx-project.json` file. It may be you are missing a default package directory, for example.

Comment: @PhilW Yes, I have done all that but no luck also, adding the sfdx-project.json file in the post

Comment: Your json looks good , can you click on package.xml file in manifest folder and try retrieve by right clicking "Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org"

Comment: @Elijah I did try that but still got the same issue

Comment: Can you run through how you set up Salesforce to VS Code, so it will be easier to see if you missed a step.
For example I do 1) SFDX: Create project from manifest 2) SFDX: Authorize an org 3) Retrieve Project from Manifest 4) Done